unable to get AWS session via AWSPowerShell in Milano Region via STS
I am using some AWSPowerShell script to get reports from my instances.
I have  old working instances in Tokio  region ap-northeast-1, new instances were deployed in Milano region eu-south-1,
To get authorized and run cmds from my local pc I am using assume roles for my account + access keys.
Problem is that when I run powershell script for Milano region, I get this error:
PS > Set-AWSCredential -ProfileName test
PS > Set-DefaultAWSRegion -Region eu-south-1
PS > Get-STSCallerIdentity
Get-STSCallerIdentity : The security token included in the request is invalid
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-STSCallerIdentity
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...rIdentityCmdlet:GetSTSCallerIdentityCmdlet) [Get-ST
   SCallerIdentity], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Amazon.SecurityToken.AmazonSecurityTokenServiceException,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.STS.G
   etSTSCallerIdentityCmdlet

when I run the same for Tokio is working fine:
 PS> Set-AWSCredential -ProfileName test
PS > Set-DefaultAWSRegion -Region ap-northeast-1
PS > Get-STSCallerIdentity
 Account      Arn                                                                                                   User
                                                                                                                   Id
-------      ---                                                                                                   ----
123 arn:aws:sts::...


when I executed similar command via aws cli for issued Milano region, its working also:
> aws sts get-caller-identity --profile test

{

    "UserId": "XYZ",

    "Account": "123",

    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::123:assumed-role/.../botocore-session-.."

}


So i am expecting that root cause is Milano region and powershell configuration
Before I have similar issue with python Boto3 script to run in Milano region,
I fixed this by adding endpoint region in my python script based on below recommendation:`
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/iam-validate-access-credentials
Short description
The AWS Security Token Service (AWS STS) supports an updated version of session tokens, version 2. New AWS Regions (for example, Bahrain) are not enabled by default and only accept the updated version of session tokens. This error can occur if version 1 session tokens are used to make a request to service endpoints in an AWS Region that are not enabled by default. For more information, see Managing AWS STS in an AWS Region.
stsclient = session.client('sts', region_name='ap-northeast-1', endpoint_url='https://sts.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com')

You can try to set this Powershell environment variable first :
$env:AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS = 'regional'
and then with Version 2 token .ps1 script should work.
